# jQuery load broken?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, jquery-load

So I noticed on jQuery when they are replace `.html()` not even their examples are working correctly. I was trying to help a user with a AJAX question and suddenly AJAX is not behaving on my test pages nor his example. In fact it doesn't add the response to `#feedback` whether set through `$('#feedback').load()` or using a function to append the data! However if you alert the data, sure enough, you have the entire page (also another issue as we should be grabbing only the body!)

What is going on with jQuery??

## Trigger Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#button').click(function () {
                    $('#feedback').load('test.htm #body', function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        $('#feedback').html(data); // Append again... y u no work!?

                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Go" />
        <div id="feedback">Welcome</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

## Test Page test.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
  <body id="body">
        Welcome again <label id="var_name" name="callBack_data" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The result for this action will `alert()` the *entire page* rather then just the body. It also will not append the data to the div.

By changing the buttons type to `type="button"` we are able to load some data to the div, however no the right selection.

## Updated Code that Works n' Stuff

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#button').click(function () {
                    $('#feedback').load('test.htm #body');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Go" />
        <div id="feedback">Welcome</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

## Test Page Update

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
  <body>
        <div id="body">
            Welcome again <label id="var_name" name="callBack_data" />
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not appending, you're replacing the HTML. And in this case you're replacing the HTML of #feedback with the entire page that was requested rather than the bit specified in the load request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.load` already does the .html portion, you don't need to do that yourself.

```
$('#feedback').load('test.htm #body');
```

Additionally, `<body>` is removed when you do `$("<div>").html("<body></body>")`, therefore targeting it by id isn't going to work. Wrap your text in a div with the `id="body"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
        Welcome again <label id="var_name" name="callBack_data" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will result in

```
<div id="feedback">
    Welcome again <label id="var_name" name="callBack_data" />
</div>
```

which will display as:

> Welcome again

Comment: That's the point, it wasn't. Please _try_ the code or read my explanation.

Comment: Actually load() is working just as it is expected to @JordanThompson. You need to look at how these things work.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No. It's not. It doesn't delegate the #body nor does it input the HTML to the div. [See their documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) You'll notice not even their "Load the main page's footer navigation into an ordered list." is working

Comment: The demo doesn't work because it was written to work with the old api site, the new one doesn't have the element being referenced. (someone should make a bug report about that)

Comment: @KevinB Explains a lot. I submitted the page as needing a update.